# Unable to escape single quote

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, tedious

I am trying to figure out a way to escape single quotes in my "pre-built" SQL query that I send to a generic functions (all my queries use it).

I tried the escape npm plugin, doing it manually, etc.

Here's the bit of code where I build my query and when I input for example "it's", well the dataString bugs out because of the special character:

```js
exports.addEntry = (req, res, nomPage, nomTable, data) => {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k, id) {
    console.log(data[k]);
    if (data[k] != null) {
      if (id > 0) {
        columnString += `,`;
        dataString += `,`;
      }
      columnString += `${[k]}`;
      dataString += `'${data[k]}'`;
    }
  });

  try {
    if (!data) throw new Error("Input not valid");
    if (data) {
      var sqlQuery = `INSERT INTO ${nomTable} (${columnString}) VALUES (${dataString})`;
      connect.connectDatabase(sqlQuery, (data, err) => { 
[...]
```

The generic function I was talking about earlier is this:

```js
var sql = require("mssql"); 
var config = require("../settings").config; 

exports.connectDatabase = function (rawQuery, callback) {
  var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
  conn
    .connect()
    .then(function () {
      var req = new sql.Request(conn);
      req
        .query(rawQuery)
        .then(function (recordset) {
          callback(recordset.recordset);
        })
```

My plan is having the queries to use only one function, not many functions that does pretty much the same thing.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can pass your values using parameters they will do all the work for you.

Comment: Dale K is 100% correct.  However if you must... replace the single quote with TWO single quotes  For example, O'Neal becomes O''Neal

Comment: There is no better (and no other) solution than to parametrise. Injection is a huge security flaw, and you should not leave such vulnerabilities in your application.

Comment: Don't replace the single quote with two single quotes. That's a recipe for disaster. Use parameters.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, passing the values using parameters would be:
var sql = SELECT * FROM ?
conn.query(sql,­[tableName]

I tried this way, but I cannot figure out how to keep my pre-built query intact and pass my values into the other function to be used like the code above this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are building up this query is exactly what you don't want to do. It leaves you completely open to SQL injection.

To avoid this, you need to parameterize your query. The added benefit here it will take care of all escaping.

Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-ver15#step-3-insert-a-row), straight from the MS docs, demonstrating how to perform parameterized queries with the node.js driver for SQL Server.

Your code, following this paradigm will look something like:

```
exports.addEntry = (req, res, nomPage, nomTable, data) => {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k, id) {
    console.log(data[k]);
    if (data[k] != null) {
      if (id > 0) {
        columnString += `,`;
        dataString += `,`;
      }
      columnString += `${[k]}`;
      dataString += `@${data[k]}`;
    }
  });

  try {
    if (!data) throw new Error("Input not valid");
    if (data) {
      var sqlQuery = `INSERT INTO ${nomTable} (${columnString}) VALUES (${dataString})`;
      connect.connectDatabase(sqlQuery, (data, err) => { 
[...]
```

All that changed was the operating constructing the `dataString`.

> Note, you'll now need to feed parameters into your command execution to replace the data you were embedding before.

Comment: is there a website to start learning about these ?
as a beginner, I am a bit lost.
I have seen the '@' being used but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: I forgot to say that I use tedious and the user input data in a non-fixed amount of parameters (Depends on the page).   Some pages will require 1 parameter, some other pages will require more than 10+. All the examples I have seen with your example seems like the amount of parameters had to be declared before even knowing how many parameters is going needed. As of now, my single function can create any query I want (without any security), I just don't know what to change to add security and keep my flexibility with this generic function.

Comment: The `?` you see are just placeholders for your parameters. You can also use named parameters as in the example which take the form of `@parameterName`. With respect to your second question, I simply would not rely on a single function to do all of my database calls. Then you eliminate any uncertainty about not only how many parameters. But also, which query to write. This pattern may even eliminate this query building you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do this :
1 - replacing the colons for square brackets which will create an array of string values then you just have to worry about sorting thru the array length, this will increase your processing time but if your app is not too big it should not make a big difference.

2 - Use `\'` to escape single quotes in strings or `\"` to escape double quotes.

Let me know if that helped as this is a quick answer.